# Proof that $2^n-1$ does not always generate primes when primes are plugged in for $n$?

Tags: prime-numbers

Exactly what the name entails. The function $2^n-1$ I see largely tends to generate primes when $n$ is prime. However, a week ago I heard that this was horribly false. Please show me a disproof.

Comment: Often when you want to prove something like this isn't true, you just search for examples.

Comment: you only need one case to disprove something, like a truth table in this case going to infinity.

Comment: Even though experimental evidence strongly suggests that for most primes, $2^p-1$ is not prime, it has not been shown that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $2^p-1$ is not prime.

Answer (score 7):

$$\Large 2^{11}-1=23\cdot 89$$
Take a look at the Wikipedia page on [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime). There are (currently) only $48$ known prime numbers $p$ such that $2^p-1$ is prime, after people have used computers to check millions.

Comment: Well that answers it